# Using xtext as third party

Tags: xtext

I want to use my xtext app as an external jar.
in order to validate a file that should be in my dsl language.

1) i don't know how to load the file to my jar.
2) any suggestions about the process?

thanks

Comment: A more recent question has received answers that might interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722707/working-with-xtext-not-as-plugin